# Is there a way to dynamically update a security group from networks in a route table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

kind of surprised there isn't a tighter integration between these two services (i thinking maybe there is but i just missed it)

I have a route table with routes to various networks and I also have it configured to propagate routes from a VPN via BGP. Thats all dynamic

Now I have an EC2 instance thats on a subnet that is using that route table

Is there some way/feature to have a security group that automatically allows inbound access from all destination routes in a route table? The route table is getting dynamically updated from BGP  would be nice to have an SG that tracks that for me so any new routes are automatically allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can have a simple Lambda function fired up every, say, 5 minutes that will scan the route table and add all the prefixes to the security group.

If the 5 mins delay between adding a route and opening the SG is too long you may have a look at *CloudWatch Events* - there may be an event triggered when a RTB is updated and again you can fire up a Lambda function when this event is triggered. That may be faster.

You can get some inspiration from [aws-ipranges-updater](https://github.com/mludvig/aws-ipranges-updater) - a lambda that can update security groups or route tables with official AWS prefixes. Modify it to your needs and add the Events trigger.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I dont want to do this with some wonky script. If i can just pull that in via a terraform datasource thats enough doesnt need to be updated in real time

Comment: @red888 /me is trying to figure out if a simple "wonky script" that runs automatically is really worse than a "wonky terraform" ran ad-hoc. Up to you, mate ;)